# powershell get-itemproperty get just value

Tags: datetime, powershell, properties

i use the following code for getting the creationtime of the psexec.exe on c:\

```
Get-ItemProperty -path c:\psexec.exe | select -property CreationTime
```

But i need ONLY the value, like "14.01.2013 16:02:53".
The output of this is:

```
 
CreationTime
------------
14.01.2013 16:02:53
```

Sure, i could trim it like remove the first 3 lines and the last 2 or loop through it, but i dont want this workaround. I assume that there HAS to be a way to just output the single value, without anything else.
I can use

```
Get-ItemProperty -path c:\psexec.exe | select -expandProperty CreationTime
```

but this gives me:

```
 
Montag, 14. Januar 2013 16:02:53
```

So there i have the empty lines too AND i want to compare this date to another date later and i think the first codeline brings the creationtime more to a datetime-formated string, so it's easier to work with it later on.

Can anyone help me with this? I searched google for hrours now but didn't find anything usefull :/

Best regards
Black Lotus

Answer (score 3):

Surround the entire command in parentheses, and use dot-notation to access the property.

```
(Get-ItemProperty -path c:\psexec.exe | select -property CreationTime).CreationTime;
```

Or you can even just do this:

```
(Get-ItemProperty -path c:\psexec.exe).CreationTime;
```

Comment: These seem functionally equivalent to the `-expandProperty` example from the question. Or what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Piping your last command to `Get-Member` reveals `TypeName: System.DateTime`. That's the same object type returned by `Get-Date`, in case that's already familiar. That object has a DateTime property. So this strips the white space:

```
Get-ItemProperty -path c:\psexec.exe | select -expand CreationTime | select -expand datetime
```

This too:

```
((Get-ItemProperty -path C:\psexec.exe).CreationTime).DateTime
```

You may find some of the [methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) handy, too, as in `(get-date).ToLongDateString()`.